# How to remove object at all index except first index in NSMutableArray IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have 1 mutablearray, i want to remove object all indexs but hold object at first index. 
EXample : Input : Array (a,b,c,d,e) 
          Output: Array (a)

Can you help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have a look at the NSMutableArray documentation before asking this question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *testArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
[testArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(1, testArray.count-1)];
```

But please make sure array count is greater than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one and put your range to remove your object.

```
[array removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(1, array.count-1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to your `a`  object (`MyObject temp = [array objectAtIndex:0]`), do `removeAllObjects`, then `insertObject:a`

Comment: This is a very bad practice since NSMutableArray class has specific APIs to do so. You must read API's documentation or even the class header file to get a better approach.